# COLCOIN - Collecting Coins

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am solving this problem - COLCOIN - Collecting Coins on spoj. 
link- https://www.spoj.com/problems/COLCOIN/

where for a given set of denominations, and money you want, the bank gives you the coins with highest denominations, until it can't anymore and then move to the next highest denomination. ex: if the denominations are [1,2,3,4,8], if you request 23 rupees, it gives you two 8 rupee coins first and as it can't give any more 8 rupee coins, moves to next denomination and gives you one 4 rupee and one 3 rupee.

The problem is to find the maximum of number of distinct denominations you can get given an input of denominations. money you request from bank is a variable, it actually shouldn't come into the picture if I am correct.

this is my idea:

try to sum up the value of lower denominations and see if they can add up to a bigger denominations,and if they are you'll never get all the smaller denominations.

ex: let's say there is 1, 2 and 5. 1+2< 5. so you can get all denominations. for 8 = 5+2+1

another: let's say there are denominations 3,4 and 5. so 3+4>5 so, we can never get all the denominations. because money will be given in denominations of 5 until the money that should be given is less than 5. and obviously you can't get 3+4= 7 rupees for something less than 5

One other idea which obviously is wrong is to start with 2nd highest denomination and find the coins which we will add upto that and return that solution+1(highest denomination). 
it is not correct because, for example, [1,2,4,17,19], if we count 19 already in try to sum up others for 18, we get 1+17, only 2 denominations other than, where as 26 would have given 4 denominations 19+4+2+1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following approach:

1. Start with the lowest denomination
2. Check if adding the next lowest denomination exceeds the denomination after that

   1. If the sum is smaller, add the denomination to the sum
   2. otherwise continue and check if the denomination one step further doesn't exceed the denomination after that.

Example: 1 3 6 8 15 20

1. different denominations d = 1, sum = 1
2. 1 + 3 < 6: d = 2, sum = 4
3. 4 + 6 >= 8: d = 2, sum = 4
4. 4 + 8 < 15: d = 3, sum = 12
5. 12 + 15 >= 20: d = 3, sum = 12
6. 12 + 20 < infinity: d = 4, sum = 32

=> answer is 4 (and the amount to withdraw is 32).

Implementation:

```js
// expects the denominations to be ordered from smallest to largest
// and also expects them to be unique
function findMaxDenominationsInSingleWithdrawal(denominations) {
    if (denominations.length <= 2)
        return denominations.length
    let sum = denominations[0], d = 1
    for (let index = 1; index + 1 < denominations.length; index++) {
        if (sum + denominations[index] < denominations[index + 1]) {
            d++
            sum += denominations[index]
        }
    }
    return d + 1
}

console.log(findMaxDenominationsInSingleWithdrawal([1, 3, 6, 8, 15, 20]))
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Works perfect.